# How do I create a class which instance can be evaluated as false?

Tags: ruby, boolean

I want to create a class `Nilly` to obtain a "pseudo-nil" object, but I need it to be evaluated as boolean `false`.

e.g.:

```
class Nilly; end

n = Nilly.new

puts n ? 'true' : 'false'    #=>  I want false here
```

How can I do that?

P.S.: I tried to do `class Nilly < NilClass`, but I coudn't use the `new` method (it was stripped out in `NilClass`).

Comment: There is no instance (thankfully :-)

Comment: There are similarities between the two questions, but they seem different enough to merit keeping both of them.  That question is about how to make an objects that acts like nil, this is how to make one that is _falsy_.  Each of these questions can have answers unique to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean logic in Ruby ONLY allows `nil` and `false` to be `falsy`

Everything else is `truthy`.

There is no way to do this.

May I ask why you want this?
What is special about your `Nilly` class?

I suggest you just call it a different way.

```
class Nilly
  def nil?
    true
  end
end
```

And use this in your logic

```
puts n.nil? ? 'false' : 'true'
```

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235322/nils-and-method-chaining), the author doesn't want to redefine `NilClass#method_missing`, for that would be very intrusive. So, I was wondering about to use an alternative class to do that.

Comment: You should look at `try` defined in `ActiveSupport`. `something.try(:a_method)` returns `nil` for `nil`, or calls `something.a_method` otherwise.

Comment: In fact, if I need only a class which `method_missing` returns `nil`, _and_ if I don't need to evaluate it as boolean, it doesn't need to inherit `NilClass`. I'll think about it.

Comment: Yeah, I think the answer is not to make a `magic nil`, but to approach your problem in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Override the new method:

```
class Nilly < NilClass
  def Nilly.new
  end
end

n = Nilly.new
puts n ? 'true' : 'false'    #=>  I want false here
```

Unlike the previous two solutions, this does exactly what you want. `n` actually evaluates as nil, without the need to test with a `nil?` method. The `to_s` solution only works because you are `puts`ing it, which implicitly calls `to_s`.

Comment: Damn, I always come too late...

Comment: you're just returning `nil`. In which case you may as well ignore the `Nilly` definition, and say `n = nil`

Comment: Nope: this does exactly what the author wants. If I read it right he wants a class "to be evaluated as boolean false". To do that, the class must be a NilClass child or a FalseClass child, *tertium non datur*. Incidentally, I am **not** returning a `nil`.

Comment: you are returning a nil. please try your code. n is EXACTLY nil. It is not an instance of Nilly.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7: `n.inspect` returns "nil". I opened `Nilly` and `def to_s; 'nilly'; end`, but `n.to_s` returns "".